# Which dependencies can be assumed to be installed on a build machine?

Tags: c, build, dependencies

We have a project that is going to require linking against `libcurl` and `libxml2`, among other libraries. We seem to have essentially two strategies for managing these depencies:

1. Ask each developer to install those libraries under the "usual" locations, e.g. `/usr/lib`, or
2. Include the sources to these libraries under a dedicated folder in the project's source tree.

Approach 1 requires everyone to make sure those libraries are installed on their system, but appears to be the approach used by many open source projects. On such projects, the build will detect that those libraries are missing and will fail.

Approach 2 might make the project tree unmanageably large in some instances and make the compilation time much longer. In addition, this approach can obviously be taken too far. I wouldn't put the compiler under the project tree, for instance (right?).

**What are the best practices wrt external dependencies? Can/should one require of every developer to have certain libraries installed to build the project? Or is considered better to include all the dependencies in the project tree?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother about their exact location in your code. Locating them should be handled by the used compiler/linker (or the user by setting variables) if they're common. For very uncommon dependencies (or ones with customized/modified files) you might want to include them in your source (if possible due to licensing etc.).

If you'd like it more convenient, you should use some script (e.g. configure or CMake) to setup/create the build files being used. CMake for example allows you to set different packages (`libcurl` and `libxml2` in your example) as optional and required. When building the project it will try to locate those, if that fails it will ask the user. This IS an additional step and might make building a bit more cumbersome but it will also make downloading faster (smaller source) as well as updating easier (as all you have to do is rebuild your program).

So in general I'd follow approach 1, if there's special/rare/customized stuff being used, approach 2.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to have the respective dependencies and have the developer install them. Later, if the project is packeted into `.deb` or `.rpm`, these packets will require the respective libraries to be installed, the source packets will have the `-devel` packets as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is *not* to include the external libraries in your source tree - instead, include a text file called `INSTALL` in your project root, which gives instructions on building the project and includes a list of the library dependencies, including minimum versions.